# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  environment: ${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}}

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-dynamodb-local

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js 
    includeModules: true   

  myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  settings:
    dev:
      ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE: sls-basic-operations-items-dev
    prod:
      ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE: sls-basic-operations-items-prod    


iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:GetItem"
        - "dynamodb:PutItem"
        - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
        - "dynamodb:ListStreams"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}.ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE}"    

# you can overwrite defaults here
stage: dev
region: us-east-1


functions:
  saveItem:
    handler: handler.saveItem
    events:
      - http:
            path: item
            method: post
 triggerStream:
    handler: handler.triggerStream
    events:
       - stream:
          type: dynamodb
          batchSize: 1
          startingPosition: LATEST
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - ImagesTable
              - StreamArn

resources:
  Resources:
    ImagesTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: "itemId"
          AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "itemId"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}.ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE}
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

The above YAML file I provided  . I tried to connect with AWS Dynamo DB using AWS LAMBDA. But once I upload the project and tried to call save item function through postman it gives the following log on AWS cloud watch. I gave the both full administrative and dynamo DB access to the IAM User. Actually I am new to AWS and pardon my English

```
      UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::247618643673:assumed-role/aws-nodejs-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/aws-nodejs-dev-saveItem is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:247618643673:table/sls-basic-operations-items-dev
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)

    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12`enter code here`)
```

Comment: It seems cut off does the log have anything after 'perform:' Looks like an assumed role does not have permission.

Comment: sorry now I provided the full log

Comment: I would check the lambda through the AWS console and see what roles are applied.

Comment: I added administrative and DynomoDB access to the IAM user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IAM role definitions should be configured under `provider` and not as a root property in your `serverless.yml`.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  environment: ${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:GetItem"
        - "dynamodb:PutItem"
        - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
        - "dynamodb:ListStreams"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}.ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
```

If you want to be more granular, you can also put that in the function level.